# yarn container-executor exit code 24 ERROR

Tags: java, apache, hadoop, containers, hadoop-yarn

I'm trying to use cgroup on yarn.

but I have some trouble.

I use 1 namenod and 3 datanodes.

I can't run container-executor.

I think I do something wrong set property, but I don't have any idea

could you help me??
If you need more information I will write comment.

yarn-site.xml

> 

```
http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
limitations under the License. See accompanying LICENSE file.
-->
<configuration>
<property>
<name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.class</name>
<value>org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.fair.FairScheduler</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>yarn.scheduler.fair.allocation.file</name>
<value>/home/hadoop/tools/hadoop/etc/hadoop/fair-scheduler.xml</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
<value>em-name01</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb</name>
<value>8192</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores</name>
<value>4</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.percentage-physical-cpu-limit</name>
<value>100</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>yarn.scheduler.fair.allow-undeclared-pools</name>
<value>false</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>yarn.scheduler.fair.preemption</name>
<value>false</value>
</property>


<!-- cgroup config -->
<property>
<name>yarn.nodemanager.container-executor.class</name>
<value>org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.LinuxContainerExecutor</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>yarn.nodemanager.linux-container-executor.nonsecure-mode.limit-users</name>
<value>false</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>yarn.nodemanager.linux-container-executor.resources-handler.class</name>
<value>org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.util.CgroupsLCEResourcesHandler</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>yarn.nodemanager.linux-container-executor.cgroups.hierarchy</name>
<value>/hadoop-yarn</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>yarn.nodemanager.linux-container-executor.cgroups.mount</name>
<value>true</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>yarn.nodemanager.linux-container-executor.cgroups.mount-path</name>
<value>/cgroup/cpu</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>yarn.nodemanager.linux-container-executor.group</name>
<value>hadoop</value>
</property>
<!--
-->
</configuration>
```

container-executor.cfg

> yarn.nodemanager.linux-container-executor.group=hadoop#configured value of           yarn.nodemanager.linux-container-executor.group
>       yarn.nodemanager.local-dirs=/tmp/hadoop-hadoop/nm-local-dir
>       banned.users=#comma separated list of users who can not run applications
>       min.user.id=500#Prevent other super-users
>       allowed.system.users=hadoop##comma separated list of system users who CAN run applications

container-executor

> [hadoop@em-name01 hadoop]$ ll $HADOOP_HOME/bin/
>
> ---Sr-s--- 1 root   hadoop 160351 Jan 26 00:20 container-executor
>
> [hadoop@em-name01 hadoop]$ ll container-executor.cfg
>
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root hadoop 389 May 27 02:38 container-executor.cfg

yarn-hadoop-nodemanager-em-data02.log
(All datanodes have same log)

> ************************************************************/
>       2016-05-27 10:45:31,586 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager: registered UNIX signal handlers                                                               for [TERM, HUP, INT]
>       2016-05-27 10:45:32,826 WARN org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.LinuxContainerExecutor: yarn.nodemanager.lin                                                              ux-container-executor.nonsecure-mode.limit-users: impersonation without authentication enabled
>       2016-05-27 10:45:32,830 WARN org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.LinuxContainerExecutor: Exit code from conta                                                              iner executor initialization is : 24
>       ExitCodeException exitCode=24: File /home/hadoop/tools/hadoop-2.7.2/etc/hadoop must be owned by root, but is owned by 500
>       at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:545)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:456)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:722)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.LinuxContainerExecutor.init(LinuxContainerExecutor.java:185)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.serviceInit(NodeManager.java:216)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.initAndStartNodeManager(NodeManager.java:485)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.main(NodeManager.java:533)
>       2016-05-27 10:45:32,832 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.ContainerExecutor:
>       2016-05-27 10:45:32,832 INFO org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService: Service NodeManager failed in state INITED;                                                               cause: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: Failed to initialize container executor
>       org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: Failed to initialize container executor
>       at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.serviceInit(NodeManager.java:218)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.initAndStartNodeManager(NodeManager.java:485)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.main(NodeManager.java:533)
>       Caused by: java.io.IOException: Linux container executor not configured properly (error=24)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.LinuxContainerExecutor.init(LinuxContainerExecutor.java:191)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.serviceInit(NodeManager.java:216)
>           ... 3 more
>       Caused by: ExitCodeException exitCode=24: File /home/hadoop/tools/hadoop-2.7.2/etc/hadoop must be owned by root, but is owned by 500
>       at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:545)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:456)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:722)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.LinuxContainerExecutor.init(LinuxContainerExecutor.java:185)
>           ... 4 more
>       2016-05-27 10:45:32,834 FATAL org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager: Error starting NodeManager
>       org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: Failed to initialize container executor
>       at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.serviceInit(NodeManager.java:218)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.initAndStartNodeManager(NodeManager.java:485)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.main(NodeManager.java:533)
>       Caused by: java.io.IOException: Linux container executor not configured properly (error=24)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.LinuxContainerExecutor.init(LinuxContainerExecutor.java:191)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.serviceInit(NodeManager.java:216)
>           ... 3 more
>       Caused by: ExitCodeException exitCode=24: File /home/hadoop/tools/hadoop-2.7.2/etc/hadoop must be owned by root, but is owned by 500
>       at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:545)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:456)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:722)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.LinuxContainerExecutor.init(LinuxContainerExecutor.java:185)
>           ... 4 more
>       2016-05-27 10:45:32,838 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager: SHUTDOWN_MSG:
>       /************************************************************
>       SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NodeManager at em-data02/58.181.37.179
>       ************************************************************/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
chown "/home/hadoop/tools/hadoop-2.7.2/etc/hadoop"
```

User owner to root.